# What happens in old mobile browsers which don't support vw or vh properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the CSS3 properties such as VW VH. i need to know the impact of old mobile browser which doesn't support the CSS3.
i am using to set the height of the div using the VH.

```
.block{
   height : 50vh;
   width  : 50vw;
}
<div class="block">
      //do some thing....
</div>
```

Comment: It will just ignore the property.

Comment: [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

Comment: Interestingly if you use vmax safari defaults it to vw.

Answer (score 2):

*I know your pain.*

On mobile browsers that don't support `vw` or `vh`, the properties are ignored and default to *inherit* on block elements' width and *collapse* on `height`, and on inline-block elements both `width` and `height` are set to *collapse*.

With `vw` units, for compatibility, you can easily switch them out for % values, but percentage height units *never* work as expected.

In PhoneGap, Cordova, and even my website which targets Android users, I use a "polyfill" (code that makes the unsupported styling "work") along with my `vw` and `vh` units to support Android 4.3 Jellybean and below:

```
function orient() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if(ua.indexOf('droid 4.3') == -1 && ua.indexOf('droid 4.2') == -1 && ua.indexOf('droid 4.1') == -1 && ua.indexOf('droid 4.0') == -1 && ua.indexOf('droid 2.') == -1) {

      //This version of Android supports vw and vh units!

    } else {

      //Polyfill!

      var w = window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight;

      //Examples:

      elem.style.width = (w*.94)+'px'; //width: 94vw
      elem.style.height = (h*.94)+'px'; //height: 94vh
      elem2.style.height = (w*.5)+'px'; //height: 50vw (Opposite viewport unit! % doesn't support that!)

    }
}
window.onresize = function() { window.setTimeout(orient,50); }
window.onresize();
```

I like Javascript because it doesn't clutter my CSS code, and doesn't execute if the browser is compatible. Better than percentage units, right?

Hope this (or a version of this) helps you on your project!

Comment: @Rob Yup. I over-reached the question, that was my bad. I edited to include default behavior on both block and inline-block elements, on both width and height.

Comment: @Aaron Gillion Thanks for information...help full for me..
from my understanding (please clarify  if i am wrong). where ever that i using the VW and vh. if th e broswer does'nt support we should to find the device or version. depends on that we have to alter with your above code right.if yes.. how can do the above approch globally.. if wrong .. please help my understanding...

Comment: @shamil You'll have to figure out which iPhone versions do not support vw/vh. The huge problem with that is for security reasons, Apple does not disclose iOS version in `userAgent` anymore, so there's actually no way to tell. However, there's no need to worry because 98% of the iPhone market share support vw/vh units.

Comment: what is the case of Android??

Comment: @shamil My code example above covers the entire Android spectrum.

Comment: You'te the best, Aaron!